# RestKit Reset Core Data Store

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

from the official RestKit page [Restkit Github](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Reset-to-a-Factory-Fresh-Persistent-Store) I found the following to reset the store:

```
- (void) resetSavedDatabase:(id)sender {
    RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore];
    [objectStore resetPersistentStores];
    [objectStore save:nil];    

}
```

That works. But if I then do the following after this method I got a error:

```
TestEntity *testEntity = [TestEntity createEntity];

testEntity.name = @"TestEntity";    

NSError *error;

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore save:&error];
```

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object's persistent store is
>   not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator'

Everything is called in the background. The idea is, that I want to preload some sqlite data and then synchronize them with my synchronize logic. (The logic is working when I do not delete the persistent store)

Can someone help me?

Comment: You deleted the store. Recreate it in the same way it is created on first run.

Comment: @Paul de Lange, I added the hyperlink.

Comment: @Mundi, as I see in the RestKit code, deletePersistentStore creates automatically a new store

Comment: @Andy `deletePersistentStore` has changed to [resetPersistentStores](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectStore.html#//api/name/resetPersistentStores:).. please update your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will automatically recreate the store, but in the following step it will also recreate an object context.

So you almost definitely want to do this on the main thread. Otherwise, RestKit will associate the created persistent store with an object context in the background thread and that will disappear when the thread ends.

I completely don't understand why you want to do this though.

Comment: I got a synchronize mechanism which is going on in the background and synchronize some xml data with restkit into core data. Sometimes the synchronize doesnt make sense and instead of synchronizing some file I want to download an existing filled sqlite Core Data file to the documentsfolder and replace the old local file with that.

Comment: Sounds complicated, but either way you will need to re-associate the persistent store with all managed object contexts. Otherwise access on one thread will crash as you have seen.

Comment: It is complicated, but its the only possible way for this case. How can I do that? When I created some objects with TestEntity *test = [TestEntity createEntity] in a background thread. How do I save this objects, can you give me an example?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to just create every object on the main thread, isnt it?

Comment: I will accept this answer, because the problem was the creation of the objects over the RestKit API in a background thread. Performing every call on the main thread solved the problem.